# Listener or rule for flutter_driver tests, to make automatically screenshot, if any one test failed

Tags: flutter, automation, integration-testing, screenshot, flutterdriver

**Hello!**

There is huge trouble with taking automatically screenshot in flutter, if any test failed in test suite. In general I mean the same solution as it working in JUnit or TestNG.
Also I'm tried to wrap all test cases in try/catch, but it didn't work properly...
Please help if have any idea how to solve it.
Thanks in advance)

**For example**

*In JUnit it's:*

```
import com.codeborne.selenide.junit.ScreenShooter;

public class MyTest {
    @rule
    public ScreenShooter makeScreenshotOnFailure = ScreenShooter.failedTests();
        // `enter code here`
}
```

*In TestNG it's:*

```
import com.codeborne.selenide.testng.ScreenShooter;

@listeners({ ScreenShooter.class})
public class MyTest {
    // `enter code here`
}
```